# FocusedItem Index and SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, listview

I'm using c# 2008 on 3.5 .NET platform

When I use:

```
int index = Listview1.SelectedIndex;
```

I'm getting:

> "Error    1   'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' does not contain a definition
>   for 'SelectedIndex' and no extension method 'SelectedIndex' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

But If I use:

```
int index = Listview1.FocusedItem.Index;
```

It works. Is there any compatibility problem of *SelectedIndex* in c# 2008 or .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 1):

[System.Windows.Forms.ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) does not have a property `SelectedIndex`. However, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx) does. It looks like you're referencing the wrong class.

If you really do need System.Windows.Forms.ListView then there is a property [SelectedIndices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices(v=vs.110).aspx)